# Singleton Class returning its property nil in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

I am trying to learn Singleton Class in Playground but dont know how to get its only one instance.Why is this singleton class returning nil while accessing its property?It would be great if someone would explain me why do i need  this Static class?

```
class SingletonC {
    var a:String?

    class var sharedInstance: SingletonC {

        struct Static {
            static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance: SingletonC? = nil
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = SingletonC()
        }

        return Static.instance!
    }
}
var ab = SingletonC()

ab.a = "fdsfds"

SingletonC.sharedInstance.a //prints nil
```

**UPDATED:**
After experimenting sometimes i got the value

```
SingletonC.sharedInstance.a = "Hello"
SingletonC.sharedInstance.a
```

*But can i obtain this by creating a object of `SingletonC`for the first time?What is the way to use Singleton class?*

Comment: assign the value in same way as you are getting its value. ... singletonC.sharedInstance.a = "fdsfds"

Comment: i want to get the value as SingletonC.sharedInstance.a ....

Comment: while you are assigning it assign as SingletonC.sharedInstance.a = "fdsfds" and then get the value as println(SingletonC.sharedInstance.a) or var b : String = SingletonC.sharedinstance.a

Comment: read for the Singleton class ... Singleton class always have only one instance you cannot use more than one instance of the class so you have to use it same way

Comment: yeah i know that..but can i create a instance for the first time as var a = SingletonC()

Comment: this will return you nil , as syntax its right but as symentics its wrong class won't allow you an other object

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a static property. Instead of `var a: String?`, use `static var a: String?`.

With that, all instances have the same value of `a`.

Call `a` by `SingletonC.a`

What your code does is you create an instance of `SingletonC` and put it in `ab`. And you set `ab`'s `a` property to `"fdsfds"` (Only `ab` instance has `a` of value `"fdsfds"`).

The third line, `SingletonC.sharedInstance.a` creates a new `SingletonC` instance and put it in `Static.instance` (creates one time only by using the `dispatch_once` function). Thus, `ab` and `sharedInstance` are different instances of `SingletonC`.

**Answer for your updated question:**

```
dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
    let instance = SingletonC()
    instance.a = "Your string"
    Static.instance = instance
}
```

Comment: yeah its working but not as i want..i dont want that variable to be static?

Comment: i tried this as var ab = SingletonC()
ab.a = "anish"

var cd = SingletonC()
cd.a
but it returns nil in the last line  and tried this too SingletonC.sharedInstance.a it returns nil too

Comment: If you want `a` to be the same for every class, you need to use a static property (as explained above). Singleton pattern is not used like that.

Answer (score -1):

As about a singleton class it have only one instances as if you are reserving the value same the way you have to assign it the value

```
class Demo{

// assign value
SingletonC.sharedInstance.a = "Your value"

//get value 
println(SingletonC.sharedInstance.a)
var b = SingletonC.shahredInstance.a

}
```

or further more if you want a simple code every time you can use it as

```
class Demo{
     let obj = Singleton.sharedInstance
    // assign value
    obj.a = "Your value"

    //get value 
    println(obj.a)
    var b = obj.a

    }
```

Both here works the same